# Can't record voice notes in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

so my friend has a samsung edge 7. whenever she tries to record or listen to a voice note on whatsapp the voice note is full of notification sounds when while recording there was no such noise. i've checked, and the phone has the latest update. ive uninstalled whatsapp and reinstalled it, no dice.

Comment: Does she use earphones/headphones when she's recording? Or maybe she gets notification when she's recording.

Comment: neither of those two things.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by recording outside of whatsapp then send it on whatsapp and see if the sound is still there.